# Is it possible to add json info to a OSM file in julia?

Tags: python, julia, openstreetmap

I'm trying to extract set of public transit nodes from open street map. After reading wikis and documentation, it seems Overpass-turbo gives nodes and edges related to public trasit. So, I did this query on [NYC](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) and once trying to export it give an option of exporting as raw osm data, however, after downloading the file is JSON not OSM file. So, having an existing .osm file of newyork city, how to integerate this json to that osm?

can OSMX.jl from julia (or python) open an existing osm file and somehow integrated this json info to the existing map?

Comment: You could use the osmium or pyosmium library

Comment: Most APIs and data extraction engines provide PBF and XML - see https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_file_formats
Are you sure that libosmium/pyosmium supports "OSM JSON" files?